# When player interacts with proximity prompt it checks if the player has a tool, if not then it does a function -ROBLOX STUDIO

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm making a gui that shows up when a player interacts with a proximity prompt, but, i want the script to check if the player has the tool in his inventory. If it has the tool then do nothing (don'
t show the gui), if it doesn't have the tool then fire an event. I tried making it but this error keeps showing up **Workspace.Part.Script:6: attempt to index nil with 'Backpack'**
Here's the script:

```
debounce = true
script.Parent.ProximityPrompt.Triggered:Connect(function(player)
    if debounce then
        debounce = false
        local noob = game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(player.Parent)
        local Tool = noob.Backpack:FindFirstChild("Gunball")
        
            if Tool == nil then
        
            game.ReplicatedStorage.RemoteEvent:FireClient(player)
            debounce = true
            end
        end
end)
```

Here's the gui script (local), even if i don't really think that is usefull..:

```
game.ReplicatedStorage.RemoteEvent.OnClientEvent:Connect(function()
    script.Parent.Visible = true
end)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workspace.Part.Script:6: attempt to index nil with 'Backpack'

```
local Tool = noob.Backpack:FindFirstChild("Gunball")
```

Here `noob` is `nil`.

So in `local noob = game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(player.Parent)` `game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(player.Parent)` returns `nil`.

According to the [Roblox documentation](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/function/Players/GetPlayerFromCharacter)

> This function returns the Player associated with the given
> Player.Character, or nil if one cannot be found. It is equivalent to
> the following function:
>
> ```
> local function getPlayerFromCharacter(character)
>   for _, player in pairs(game:GetService("Players"):GetPlayers()) do
>       if player.Character == character then
>           return player
>       end
>   end
> end
> ```

So it seems that the `Parent` of `player`, `player.Parent` is not a `Character` associated with any player.

Why should a player property like `Character` be a parent of a player? I'm no Roblox expert but that doesn't seem to make any sense to me.

If you want to check wether the player who triggered the ProximitPrompt has some item, why not work with `player`? I mean that's the player who triggered it. So check its backpack, not some parent character stuff.

Comment: Good writeup. I think I can understand how they ended up with this mistake. A lot of traditional [object.touched events](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/event/BasePart/Touched) deal with parts of a player's character, which is why you'd see this part.parent > character > getPlayerFromCharacter song and dance. It's nice that this event directly gives you the player object.

Comment: thank you! Im pretty new to scripting and i don't  know that much, your answer was really helpfull